# Show soft input keyboard

Tags: android, android-view, android-input-method

I'm trying to show the soft input keyboard for a view on the touch event.
This line works:

```
inputManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(),0,0);
```

But this line doesn't work:

```
inputManager.showSoftInput(this,0);
```

Why is it so? What if I want to connect the soft input to the view?
Thanks.

Comment: you are testing on emulator or on real device? I think it will not open the keyboard on AVD but it will open on device, which does not have `Hard key board`

Comment: It's indeed on an emulator. So the reason for the soft input not opening is that the emulator has a hard keyboard?

Comment: I think so..try on a device which does not have hard hard keyboard..

Comment: Is there a way to make the emulator think there's no hard keyboard?

Comment: I think...Click on AVD manger > open you targeted AVD > Edit >Hardware > New > Keyboard Support > OK > Make it "NO"

Comment: Thanks, it worked, so there's no way to use both hard and soft keyboards in this case?

Comment: Can you also please write it as an answer to the question, so I'll be able to accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are testing on emulator. not on real device?

It will not open the `keyboard` on AVD but it will open on real device, which does not have `Hard key board`.

To test it on `AVD` you need to disable the keyboard.

To disable keyboard use

```
Click on AVD manager > open you targeted AVD > Edit > Hardware > New > Keyboard Support > OK > Make it "NO"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: just implement onClickListener onView. then in onClick do this.

Comment: As I said in the original message, I know toggleSoftInput works, but I want to use showSoftInput because it accepts a View parameter.

Answer (score 2):

try this in onclick event.

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
            (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: I know toggleSoftInput works, but I want to use showSoftInput because it accepts a View parameter and I want to connect the view to the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

`showSoftInput()` won't work unless your `View` has focus. Moreover, calling `requestFocus()` does not give your `View` focus unless you first call `setFocusableInTouchMode()` and/or `setFocusable()` to true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request focus first and show the soft input as follows:

```
    mEditTextStudy.requestFocus();
    mEditTextStudy.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager imm =
                            (InputMethodManager)
                                    getActivity()
                                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (imm != null) {
                        imm.showSoftInput(mEditTextStudy, SHOW_FORCED);
                    }
                }
            });
```